# Center text around middle char of string

Tags: html, css, centering, typography, html-input

I have an element containing some text and want to center the text inside the element in a way that the most center char should be in the middle of the element. E.g. given the string "iiiii|MMMMM" the "|" is the most center char, yet in a non mono-space font it is - if centered normally - further to the left. The "|" should be at the center of the element regardless of the character width of the other chars.
The element is also an input, so I cant split the string in to its chars.

Hope you have some ideas, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share the requirement in visuals. Like an image or something

Comment: I sadly cant since i dont know how to code it

Comment: You can only cut strings,What if I put in more than one |?

Comment: I cant cut strings

Answer (score 0):

You can't align a character without cutting the string.

```js
var arr = [];

var text1 = document.querySelector('#text1');
var text2 = document.querySelector('#text2');

document.querySelector('#textInput').addEventListener("input", function(){
  arr = textInput.value.split('|')
 
  text1.innerText = arr[0] || ''
  text2.innerText = arr[1] || ''
})
```

```css
.text-wrap{
  width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px orange;
  font-size: 0;
}
.text-wrap span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.text-wrap span:nth-child(1n){
  width: calc(50% - 3px);
}
.text-wrap span:nth-child(2){
  width: 6px;
  text-align: center;
}
.text-wrap span:nth-child(1){
  text-align: right;
  text-indent: -99999px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-wrap">
    <span id="text1">aaaadddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</span>
    <span>|</span>
    <span id="text2">bb</span>
</div>
<input type="text" id="textInput"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use css flex

```css
.flex-row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

div{
  flex: 1;
}

span{
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.text-right{
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="text-right">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <span>|</span>
  <div>bbb</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had the same Idea, but my element is a single input which I sadly cant split up